# Can't get special characters to render using Open Sans font?

Tags: uwp

I have a UWP app with a text block that renders the alpha character using the Open Sans font. But the correct character is not rendered the unsupported character is...

Any ideas on how to get a UWP apps text block to render the correct font?

When I install the font into my Windows 10 machine the font renders correctly in notepad but not in my UWP app which references the same font family.

I know my UWP is rendering the correct font because I can see the difference between the don't and the default font.. The normal alpha numeric characters are rendering correctly.

Any ideas?

Comment: Hm, a line of code to reproduce this issue would be very useful to the people who are willing to help you.

Comment: You would need to use  converter on your text block and return the new font that you need in your converter, which may fix your issue

Answer (score -1):

I’m not sure how you render the Open Sans font in your UWP app, I recommend you add the custom font file(.ttf or etc.) into the Assets folder, then set the font with FontFamily property：

```
<TextBlock
    FontFamily="ms-appx:///Assets/OpenSans-Bold.ttf#Open Sans"
    FontSize="36" 
    Text="Hello, this is OpenSans-Bold Style"/>
<TextBlock
    FontFamily="ms-appx:///Assets/OpenSans-BoldItalic.ttf#Open Sans"
    FontSize="36" 
    Text="Hello, this is OpenSans-BoldItalic Style" />
<TextBlock
    FontFamily="ms-appx:///Assets/OpenSans-ExtraBold.ttf#Open Sans"
    FontSize="36" 
    Text="Hello, this is OpenSans-ExtraBold Style" />
<TextBlock
    FontFamily="ms-appx:///Assets/OpenSans-Light.ttf#Open Sans"
    FontSize="36" 
    Text="Hello, this is OpenSans-Light Style" />
```

The FontFamily format is like [FontFilePath]#[FontName], **note that the FontName must be “Open Sans” in my test**.

You also can set it in the code behind like:

```
MyTextBlock.FontFamily = new FontFamily("/Assets/OpenSans-Light.ttf#Open Sans");
```

--------------Edit---------------------------------------------------------

Please provide some code and screenshots for more details, am I misunderstand something here? What specific character does not work here? Do you mean something like "β" which is not working?

[image]

Comment: yeah I'm doing this ;) but it doesn't render special characters

Comment: @visc I have some edit in the answer. Can you check whether my understanding is right here?